# Inverting case: (aPPLE to Apple, BLUeBeRrY to bluEbErRY)

Tags: c#, .net

In my following code, the output is `Upper:APPLE` and `Lower:apple`, but I need aPPLE to become Apple, and BLUeBeRrY to become bluEbErRY.

```
string[] words = {"aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };

var upperLowerWords = from w in words
                      select new { Upper = w.ToUpper(), 
                                   Lower = w.ToLower() };

foreach (var ul in upperLowerWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Uppercase: {0}, Lowercase: {1}", ul.Upper, ul.Lower);
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `ToTitlecase`.

Answer (score 3):

Using some more Linq magic:

```
string[] words = { "aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };

var upperLowerWords = from w in words
                        select new
                        {
                            Upper = w.ToUpper(),
                            Lower = w.ToLower(),
                            Original = w,
                            Changed = new string(w.Select(s=> char.IsLower(s) ? char.ToUpper(s) : char.ToLower(s)).ToArray())
                        };

foreach (var ul in upperLowerWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}, Uppercase: {1}, Lowercase: {2}, Changed: {3}", ul.Original, ul.Upper, ul.Lower, ul.Changed );
}
```

Comment: If a character is already lowercase then there is no need for `char.ToLower` in the conditional expression of the inner `Select`. (And I should not the assumption that there is just upper and lower cases only really applies to a subset of latin alphabet based languages: some have no cases, including Gaelic, some add title case).

Comment: If a character is lower case, I make it uppercase , otherwise (the character is uppercase), I make it lowercase. Let's just assume the user is using it for a non-gaelic/arabic/hebrew/chinese etc.  website.

Answer (score 1):

How about throwing in some extension methods:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string InvertCases(this string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return value;

        var chars = value.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
            chars[i] = char.IsLower(chars[i]) ? char.ToUpper(chars[i]) : char.ToLower(chars[i]);

        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

and your use would be

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] words = { "aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };

    foreach (var ul in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}, Inverted: {1}", ul, ul.InvertCases());
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Many ways lead to Rome...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] words = { "aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };   
var upperLowerWords = from w in words    
                      select new { Original = w, Changed = ChangeCases(w) };   
foreach (var ul in upperLowerWords)   
{   
   Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}, Changed: {1}",    
        ul.Original, ul.Changed);   
}

static string ChangeCases(string input)   
{   
    string result = string.Empty;   

    foreach (char ch in input)   
    {                   
        result += Char.IsUpper(ch) ? ch.ToString().ToLower() : ch.ToString().ToUpper();   
    }   
    return result;   
}
```

Comment: you might try formatting your answer and remove the line numbers from the code.

Comment: I like the static function for changing case (I'd call it `InvertCase`), but it is preferable to use @Gidon's approach of `new string(char[])` rather than repeated concatenation.

Comment: I guess my second solution might be a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *Linq* with `char.IsXXX` and `char.ToXXX` methods

```
  string source = "StaCkOverFloW";

  string result = string.Concat(source.Select(c => char.IsLower(c)
    ? char.ToUpper(c) : char.IsUpper(c)
    ? char.ToLower(c) : c));
```

...

```
  // sTAcKoVERfLOw 
  Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For ASCII only letters, you can XOR the 6th bit:

```
string[] words = { "aPPLE", "BlUeBeRrY", "cHeRry" };

var result = words.Select(s => string.Concat(s.Select(c => (char)(c ^ ' '))));

Debug.Print(string.Join(", ", result));    // "Apple, bLuEbErRy, ChErRY"
```